# Material UI multiselect checkbox remove selected Item

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 material ui multiselect fomrcontrol with checkbox. those are binding from json file. One for listing the States and one more for Listing the Districts of Selected States. Selection is working fine, But I have a Problem while un checking the checkbox.

The Problem is, For Example when I select the state GOA & Karnataka, and corresponding Districts of those states will be displayed in District formControl. I can Select the Districts of my choice say I have selected 'North GOA'. If i uncheck 'GOA' in state dropdown, i want to clear the that states(GOA) all districts I have selected in Districts dropdown (i.e 'North GOA' need to be removed).

Please help me find the desired output
[SandBox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-germain-ue7dt)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you uncheck a selected state, you need to filter the districts, and remove the ones belong to the unchecked state:

```
  isDistrictInSelectedState = (district, statesSelected) => {
    return statesSelected.find(selectedState => {
      const districtsInState = StateDistrict.states.find(state => state.state === selectedState).districts;

      return districtsInState.find(districtInState => districtInState === district);

    })
  }

  handleChangeState = event => {
    // console.log(event.target.value)
    this.setState({
      sp_StatesCovered: event.target.value,
      sp_DistrictsCovered: this.state.sp_DistrictsCovered.filter(district => {
        return this.isDistrictInSelectedState(district, event.target.value);
      })
    });
  };
```

[image: Edit Invisible Backdrop]